# How to Assign a particular result got from SQL can be set to a variable in spark/Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Let say I have a value from `SQL` Script which I passed with `Spark.SQL`

```
results = spark.sql("SELECT EndDate FROM countDirectorySize WHERE Path IN (SELECT Path FROM countDirectorySize WHERE EndDate = (SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM countDirectorySize)) ORDER BY EndDate DESC LIMIT 1")
print(results.show())
```

O/P-

```
+----------+
|   EndDate|
+----------+
|2020-06-08|
+----------+
```

I want to set `2020-06-08` to a variable and pass it to a Python script.

Comment: do `variable=results.collect()[0][0]`

Comment: @murtihash Worked...Thanks allot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other ways can be

```
 OPTION 1: end_date = results.take(1)[0][0]


 OPTION 2: end_date = results.first()[0]
```